# Is there any formula to know how fork() makes near-perfect copy of the current process?

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{    
    int i, n=1; 

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) { 
        fork();
        printf("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I am confused if I put n=1, it prints Hello 2 times.

- If n=2, it prints Hello 8 times
- If n=3, it prints Hello 24 times..
- and so on..

Comment: Yes; it just copies all of the process' memory

Comment: It depends on the operating system. Fortunately the most popular POSIX systems have their source available for you to read *exactly* what happens when doing `fork`.

Comment: Is their is any standard formula to know how fork() makes near-perfect copy of the current process? @Joachim

Comment: @Sudheesh we can read, you don't have to repeat yourself :)

Comment: The only answer to that is: No, there is no "standard formula".

Comment: Although I suspect the question is really "Is there a formula to predict how many times Hello will be printed"

Comment: If it's like Useless proposes, then you have to remember that `fork` creates a new copy of the *process* that starts running with the statement after the `fork` call. And as your process have a loop, after the first fork both processes will continue that loop, including then forking new processes.

Comment: And you should ask what happens when the `SIGCHLD` is posted in the parent and when fully or line buffered streams are flushed...

Comment: Are you sure the number of `Hello`'s isn't 2, 6 and 14?

Comment: @EOF I am damn sure!! the number of Hello is 2, 8 and 24

Comment: @Sudheesh Wow, this is the weirdest thing: I made a test program using `puts()` instead of `printf()`, and got 2, 6 and 14 messages. A bit of testing revealed that the **newline** changes the number of messages printed. Test it by adding \n to the end of your printf, like so: `printf("Helo!\n");`. What the???

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` always makes a perfect copy of the current process -- the only difference is the process ID).

Indeed in most modern operating systems, immediately after `fork()` the two processes share exactly the same chunk of memory. The OS makes a new copy only when the new process writes to that memory (in a mode of operation called "copy-on-write") -- if neither process ever changes the memory, then they can carry on sharing that chunk of memory, saving overall system memory.

But all of that is hidden from you as a programmer. Conceptually you can think of it as a perfect copy.

That copy includes all the values of variables at the moment the `fork()` happened. So if the `fork()` happens inside a `for()` loop, with `i==2`, then the new process will **also** be mid-way through a `for()` loop, with `i==2`.

However, the processes do not *share* `i`. When one process changes the value of `i` after the `fork()`, the other process's `i` is not affected.

To understand your program's results, modify the program so that you know which process is printing each line, and which iteration it is on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
# include <sys/types.h>

main() {
    int i , n=4;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++); {
        int pid = getpid();
        if(fork() == 0) {
            printf("New process forked from %d with i=%d and pid=%d", pid, i, getpid());
        }
        printf("Hello number %d from pid %d\n", i, getpid());
    }
}
```

Since the timing will vary, you'll get output in different orders, but you should be able to make sense of where all the "Hellos" are coming from, and why there are as many as there are.

Comment: I would cast `getpid()` to `int` or even `long` (and in that case change `printf` format specifier) in the call to `printf` just to make sure that no undefined behaviour arises. If `pid_t` happens to be wider or narrower than `int`, this code will break

Comment: main with default int? Ugh!

Comment: Both of you: don't confuse the noob. This is enough to demonstrate the principle.

Comment: If fork() returns a negative value, the creation of a child process was unsuccessful.
    fork() returns a zero to the newly created child process.
    fork() returns a positive value, the process ID of the child process, to the parent. The returned process ID is of type pid_t defined in sys/types.h. Normally, the process ID is an integer. Moreover, a process can use function getpid() to retrieve the process ID assigned to this process.

Comment: <pre><code>#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>

#define   MAX_COUNT  200
#define   BUF_SIZE   100

void  main(void)
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    i;
     char   buf[BUF_SIZE];

     fork();
     pid = getpid();
     for (i = 1; i <= MAX_COUNT; i++) {
          sprintf(buf, "This line is from pid %d, value = %d\n", pid, i);
          write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
     } 
}</pre></code>

Answer (score 1):

There's is no single "formula" how it's done as different operating systems do it in different ways. But what `fork()` does is it makes a copy of the process. Rough steps that are usually involved in that:

- Stop current process.
- Make a new process, and initialize or copy related internal structures.
- Copy process memory.
- Copy resources, like open file descriptors, etc.
- Copy CPU/FPU registers.
- Resume both processes.

Answer (score 1):

you dont only fork the 'main' prozess, you also fork the children!
first itteration:

```
m -> c1
//then
m -> c2   c1-> c1.1
m -> c3   c1-> c1.1  c2->c2.1  c1.1 -> c1.1.1
```

for i = ....

write it in down this way:

```
main
fork
         child(1)
fork                  child(2)
         fork                     child(1.1)
fork                                          child(3)
         fork                                             child(1.2)
                      fork                                             child(2.1)
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

When you fork() you create a new child process that has different virtual memory but initially shows in the same physical memory with the father. At that point both processes can only read data from the memory. If they want to write or change anything in that common memory, then they use different physical memory and have write properties to that memory. Therefore when you fork() your child has initially the same i value as its father, but that value changes separately for every child.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a formula:

`fork()` **makes exactly one** near-identical copy of the process. It returns twice, however. Once in the original process (the parent, returning the child pid) and once in the child (returning 0).